# calling template class constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm getting hard time figuring out solution for calling constructor of class which uses templates.

--Header file

```
template <class Item>
class Binary_tree
{
    string file_name;
    list<Item> arr_data;
public:
    Binary_tree(string fname);
    void printArr();
};
```

--cpp file

```
template <typename Item>
Binary_tree<Item>::Binary_tree(string fname)
{
    File_Name = fname;
    total = 0;
    root = nullptr;

    std::ifstream filestream(fname);
    string line;

    while (!filestream.eof())
    {
        filestream >> line;
        arr_data.push_back(line);
    }
}

template <typename Item>
void Binary_tree<Item>::printArr()
{
    int size = arr_data.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "arr_data [" << i << "] is: " << arr_data[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

--main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 Binary_tree<string> test(file); 
 test.printArr();

 return 0;
}
```

Right now I'm getting LNK1120 and LNK2019 errors.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is `file`?

Comment: Because `test` is likely being picked up as a function declaration not a variable.

Comment: file is the name of file, the constructor is gonna use that file to read data and add it to list defined in Binary_tree class.

Comment: Which part of "create a **new** question" is unclear to you?

Answer (score 4):

**Note**: this answer answers the *original* question which was replaced by an entirely different qestion!

The declaration is for a function as is described at [the Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse):

```
Binary_tree<string> test(Binary_tree<string>(file));
```

This declares a function named `test()` returning a `Binary_tree<string>` and taking an argument or type `Binary_tree<string>` named `file`. Here are variations for fixing the problem:

```
Binary_tree<string> test0(file);
Binary_tree<string> test1 = Binary_tree<string>(file);
Binary_tree<string> test2{Binary_tree<string>(file)};
```

Comment: I tried all of them, and keep getting following 4 LNK errors.
LNK2019 and LNK1120

Comment: @Gaurav: sure. You need to define the function templates and I guess you do so in a separate .cpp file (you don't show the code to I need to use my clairvoyance which isn't entirely reliable). If you put the definition of function templates into a .cpp file you'll need to explicitly instantiate them (there are plenty questions and answers on this topic) of see my [blog](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/22/source-organization-of-templates/). The easiest approach is to put the definition of the function templates into the header to have the compiler implicitly instantiate them.

Comment: I looked at your page, and I know the concept and mostly I'm implementing it as you showed as well. If you want to see my code then here it is: 

'#include "BinaryTree.h"

template <typename Item>
Binary_tree<Item>::Binary_tree(string fname)
{
 File_Name = fname;
 total = 0;
 root = nullptr;

 std::ifstream filestream(fname);
 string line;

 while (!filestream.eof())
 {
  filestream >> line;
  arr_data.push_back(line);
 }
}


int main()
{
 string file = "HeapQuestions.txt";
 Binary_tree<string> test(file);// = (Binary_tree<string>(file));
 
 test.printArr();

 return 0;
}'

Comment: @Gaurav: so you have your template definitions in a .cpp which is probably **not** what you want! Put the code into `BinaryTree.h` and it should compile. Whether it would work I don't know. I spotted the use of `.eof()` in your code which is certainly wrong! You need to check *after* reading, e.g., using `while (filestream >> line) { ... }` (which wouldn't read a line but rather just one word; if you want to read a line you'd use `std::getline(filestream, line)`).
Not that you should **not** paste code into comment, either! You'd rather update your question...

Comment: `#include "BinaryTree.h"

template <typename Item>
Binary_tree<Item>::Binary_tree(string fname)
{
 File_Name = fname;
 total = 0;
 root = nullptr;

 std::ifstream filestream(fname);
 string line;

 while (!filestream.eof())
 {
  filestream >> line;
  arr_data.push_back(line);
 }
}


int main()
{
 string file = "HeapQuestions.txt";
 Binary_tree<string> test(file);// = (Binary_tree<string>(file));
 
 test.printArr();

 return 0;
}`

Comment: I have c++ file structure right.. I used header files and cpp files. Also, I have checked that reading file is right as well.

Comment: Clearly, the link errors are unrelated to the original question: create a new question for the link error and post a minimal example showing the problem there (make sure it isn't a duplicate of the many questions of people who use the same incorrect placement of template code as you do, though: despite you telling me that your got the file structure right, I can  tell you that you don't: read the blog article I posted above until you understand it...).

Answer (score 0):

You've encountered the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

```
Binary_tree<string> test(Binary_tree<string>(file));
```

This is a function declaration, just like

```
Binary_tree<string> test(Binary_tree<string> file);
```

... which declares a function named `test`, which accepts a `Binary_tree<string>` as it's parameter, and returns a `Binary_tree<string>`.

Comment: I want to create an Binary_tree<string> object which I can use later to call it's methods. Right now I'm unable to call printArr function. I keep getting errors like: Expression must have class type.